# Удалить "ui-slider" и сделать "select option" с сохранением js параметров

Tags: jquery-ui, slider, jquery, javascript

парни, выручайте, есть jQuery ui-slider, который передает и считает параметры в js, нужно заменить его на выпадающий список( удалить слайдер и оставить выпадающий список ) с сохранением передаваемых параметров, с html разметкой проблем нет, есть проблема с Js.

вот js код слайдера который передает параметр:

```
$pageSlider.slider({
        animate: true,
        value: 0,
        min: 1,
        max: 16,
        step: 1,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
                $pages.val(ui.value);
                $slideCalc.click();
        }       
});
```

я уже голову сломал каким образом переписать данный код чтобы select option так же передавал нужные значения.

UPD:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rn9y/7/) - собственно слайдер с js параметрами

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Jegn/163/) - то, что хотелось бы получить, но не пойму как передать js параметры

Comment: @eicto добавил, спасибо

Comment: @eicto только заметил ваш пример, я немного о другом, я хочу  вообще удалить ui-slider, и сделать вместо него select option, возможно, я в самом вопросе немного неверно выразился

Comment: а зачем вы вообще слайдер создаете-то ? создайте опции да и всё, что за идея удалить... если очень-очень надо, то возьмите параметры min-max,step и сделайте из них циклом опции. (`for (var i=min;i<max;i+=step) {$select.append($('option').text(i).val(i));}

Comment: опции берутся так:

    // getter
    var min = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "min" );

Comment: а можно ваш скайп? я вам проект покажу, посоветуйте как лучше

Comment: скайп нельзя, но ваше дело я бы решил вот так: http://plnkr.co/edit/I1yeZ0FzgSr9Y7OLJ6pK?p=preview